# Can a menu item slow down drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

In my hook_menu I have defined the following menu item:

```
 $items['import_general']=array(
        'title' => 'Import General Journal Articles',
        'description' => 'import General',
        'page callback' => 'import_general',
        'access callback' => TRUE
        );
```

Can defining the menu item without calling it through example.com/import_general slow down the system? I am having some doubts that it is slowing down my website.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can slow down your website. It is just a registered path in the DB. Comment it out then clear all cache and you will see by yourself that there is no speed difference.